# How can I view instance variables in other stack frames with Eclipse Java debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, instance-variables, stack-frame

When I'm at a breakpoint in my Java app under Eclipse debugger, I click on another frame in the stack frame list (on the same thread), expecting to be able to view some of my variables.  There's only one variable, **this**, and when I reveal what it contains, it appears to have nothing but what I assume are special runtime variables like **blocker**, **blockerLock**, **contextClassLoader**, **daemon**, **me** (which appears to just be **this**), etc.

What I want to see are the instance variables of one of my objects.  Am I misunderstanding the debugger here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no debug information compiled into class, you may not be able to see variables on the stack frame inside methods of this class. It's independent on IDE.

Comment: I've looked in Debug configurations and Preferences but am unable to find any option to compile in debug info.  Anyone have an idea how to do this in Eclipse?